# How to restrict text box length in HTML using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to restrict my Comments text box within 40 characters. I have used max=40.Its not working. Anyone please help me to fix this issue

Code:

```
<label for="cmds">Comments</label>
<input type="text" max="40" class="form-control" id="cmds" name="cmds" 
       data-ng-model="Audit.cmds" placeholder="null" >
```

Comment: My COde<input type="text" max="40" class="form-control" id="cmds" name="cmds" data-ng-model="Audit.cmds" placeholder="null" >

Comment: Use `ng-maxlength` for that: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength

Comment: max tag should not be used?

Comment: ng-maxlength can also be used for text as well?

Comment: Just replace `max` with `ng-maxlength`, as you can see in the link attached to my previous comment. If you want to restrict a number of characters the user can enter, use HTML `maxlength` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with comments, its better to use textarea instead of input type="text".

By using textarea you can do:

```
<textarea maxlength="40" id="comments" cols="" rows="">
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/akshaymhatre89/L8fky10q/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="cmds">Comments</label>
<input type="text"  ̶m̶a̶x̶=̶"̶4̶0̶"̶ class="form-control" id="cmds" name="cmds" 
       data-ng-model="Audit.cmds" placeholder="null" 
       ng-maxlength="40" />
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-maxlength Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength).